# Write a good upper bound on the absolute value of the remainder $R_1(r) = \sin{x} - P_1(x)$, using knowledge about the derivatives of $\sin{x}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let, $P_1(x)$ and $R_1(x)$ be the first-order Taylor polynomial and the remainder of the Taylor series expansion of the function $f(x)=\sin{x}$ centered at $a=0$.

Write down a good upper bound on the absolute value of the remainder $R_1(x) = \sin(x)-P_1(x)$, using your knowledge about the derivatives of $\sin(x)$. The goal here is to show that $\frac{R_1(x)}{x}$ is negligible.

**My answer :**

$$|R_1(x)| = |\sin{x}-x| \\
  \implies \frac{x^2}{2}.|\sin{c}| = |\sin{x}-x| \\
  \implies |\sin{x}-x| \le \frac{x^2}{2}$$ $$ [\text{since,} \ |\sin{c}| \le 1]
$$.
But where to go from here? How can I find an upper bound like this??

Comment: aren't you done? You've shown $|R_1(x)|=|\sin x-x|\leq \frac{x^2}{2}$, and thus for $x\neq 0$, $\left|\frac{R_1(x)}{x}\right|\leq \frac{|x|}{2}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: I'm asking that only, am I done? By upper bound, do I need to show a functional upper bound or a numerical upper bound? @peek-a-boo

Comment: there is no numerical upper bound valid on all of $\Bbb{R}$ (i.e the function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, $f(x)=\sin x-x$ is unbounded). We can only find an upper bound if we restrict to closed and bounded intervals $[a,b]$ (but you should know this trivially from the extreme value theorem). So, what you've done is perfectly fine.